# Repeat Timer Event 10 times then end it?

Tags: vb.net

How would I make a Timer that when its ran runs most of its code 10 times then after then 10th time it runs Timer2.Stop()

The code below makes the monster move right 5 pixels then stop, i want it to move one pixel 5 times then run the right.Stop() and Timer1.start()

If someone could help me fix this that would be awesome :D

```
 Private Sub right_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles right.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
        Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 5, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
    End If
    right.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub right_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles right.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    Static moveCount as Integer = 1
    If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
        Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
    End If
    moveCount += 1
    ' edit this for how many times you want it to move
    If moveCount = 5 Then
        right.Stop()
        moveCount = 1
        Timer1.Start()
    End If     
End Sub
```