# Run Random event once?

Tags: vb.net

The code below runs and keeps repeating over and over again. I only pasted the up_timer but others  do the same. Any ideas on how to make it run once, then repeat to the random loop and so on?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Application.DoEvents()
    Randomize()
    Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((4 * Rnd()) + 1))
    If value = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Up")
        up.Start()
    ElseIf value = 2 Then
        MsgBox("Down")
        down.Start()
    ElseIf value = 3 Then
        MsgBox("Left")
        left.Start()
    ElseIf value = 4 Then
        MsgBox("Right")
        right.Start()
    End If
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub up_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles up.Tick
    Static moveCount As Integer = 1
        If Me.mob2.Location.Y > 12 Then
            Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X, Me.mob2.Location.Y - 5)
    End If
    moveCount += 1
    If moveCount = 10 Then
        moveCount = 1
        Me.Timer1.Start()
        Me.up.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe, in more detail, what exactly it is you want the code to do.  It's currently unclear what you are asking.  Also, I feel compelled to mention that you should use the `Random` class rather than the old VB6-style `Randomize` and `Rnd` methods.  Also, even if you were to use `Randomize`, you should only call it once, such as when the form loads.  Also, under no circumstance, should you ever be calling `Application.DoEvents`.

Comment: not sure WHICH timer you are having trouble with, but the UP timer is only being disabled when MoveCount=10...and you should start accepting and/or upvoting some of the answers you are getting

Comment: Put many timers on your form and wait for disaster - stop doing it

Comment: Timer1 runs 3 random cases (1, 2, 3 or 4) So Im having trouble with Timer1 The random Event.

Comment: @T.S. I was trying to avoid that by doing a loop in the up timer... But the up timer works so its only the Timer1-Tick random event that needs fixing.

Comment: Are you in the same class as Meatie? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978078/repeat-timer-event-10-times-then-end-it

Comment: yea im in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you need, based on your complaint that timer1 repeats same numbers

```
Dim rand1 As New Random(CInt(Date.Now.Ticks And &h0000FFFF))
Dim value As Integer = rand1.Next(1, 4)
```

This will not repeat

Plus, you have to move `Timer1.Stop()` to beginning of the method

Comment: Thanks, that worked great :D I figured out that the message boxes were making it break, it works great now :)